# Does Ira Gamagori have an official height?

Tags: kill-la-kill

Ira Gamagori is a pillar of strength and a very large man, But his height seems to change vastly throughput the show.

Smaller:

[image] 
[image]

Larger:

[image][image]

Obviously his height changes to emphasise his largeness, but is there any official word on the height that Gamagori is meant to be? Perhaps in a character profile or something similar?

Comment: There's an Elite 4 size reference: http://i.imgur.com/ktduUbn.jpg

Comment: Gamgori has only one size: Bigger than you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The below height chart has been circulating around the internet:

[image]

But I don't think it's accurate, so I did some rough calculations using a different source.

The circulated chart puts Gamagori at 2.69m or 8" 8'

[KillLaKill.com](http://www.killlakill.com/character/) have some character profiles on their site of the different characters.

If we assume Ryuko has the average female Japanese height - 158 cm (5 ft 2 in), then we could estimate Gamagori's height by resizing the images so that the scale of the characters is more reasonable. I used head size for this, as the differences should be smaller than if we compared other features:

1.58m * 1.66 Ryukos = 2.6228m or 8"7'. This is quite similar to the above image

[image]

There are obviously lots of flaws in this calculation. Scaling was based off of visual inspection, Ryuko may not be the average female height, not using the standard Nonon unit of measurement, etc. But it does give a certain range that his height may fall in.

Comment: one thing that bother me is Nonon's height, if this scale is true then Nonon should be around 1.2 m, why did you also measure her hat?

Comment: That's the chart that has been circulating, which I was a bit doubtful of for a couple of reasons, one of them being Nonon and her hat. I'll reword the intro to make it clearer